# MYSQL ON UPDATE CASCADE only for 1 column

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

```
       tbl_tag
--------|------
name        count
apple         2
orange        5


     tbl_lookup_tag
--------|---------
doc_id        tag
1            apple
1            orange
2            apple

  foreign key (tag) references tbl_tag (name)
    on update cascade on delete cascade
```

What I want is for `tbl_lookup_tag.tag` to only be updated when `tbl_tag.name` is changed and NOT when `tbl_tag.count` is changed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referring to `tbl_tag` by name - create surrogate primary key (integer, autoincrement) and refer by it.

In that case you could rename your tags without worries and headache.

So your new schema would look like:

```
tbl_tag: id | name | count
          ^
          |----------------|
                           v
tbl_lookup_tag: doc_id | tag_id
```

Comment: True, however I was trying to eliminate another `JOIN`...but looks like I will have to go this route.

Comment: @Justin B: for what reason? If you experience any performance issues - then it is already another story and probably another question

Comment: Every document has about 10 'tag' like attributes that each describe a certain characteristic. Each attribute requires 2 tables and hence 2 joins...and so minimum 20 joins for each doc. Not so bad though for pagination. I have to use a search indexer to do any filtering.

Comment: @Justin B: you can select all the documents in a separate query, and all correspondent tags in another one. So - 2 queries for any amount of documents, without joins.